# How to run a zip target in build.xml

Tags: java, netbeans, build.xml

i want to run a zip target in build.xml while building the project (clean and build)

```
<target name="zipme" description="Zip the application to the sample project"> 
<property name="build.classes.dir" location="/home/NetBeansProjects/AdditionalSamples"/>
<property name="examples" location="${build.classes.dir}/src/org/myorg/additionalsamples/"/>
<zip basedir="../MySampleApplication" destfile="${examples}/MySampleApplicationProject.zip">
<exclude name="**/build/"/>
 <exclude name="**/dist/"/> 
<exclude name="**/nbproject/private/"/>
</zip>
</target>
```

Comment: ant zip? Or u mean how to configure netbeans to create zip build as default build task?

Comment: i have actually a moudle, that has many templates, and i want to update the templats sources, when change happens in the original templates , so when i make build for the module i will get the updates from the original templates and replace with zip files that's i have it in the Module
something like this 
https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-projectsamples.html
the target works only when i do run target by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task zipme depends on clean, but why it depends on build-init? This is incorrect. When u run build it suppose to run zipme on some stage, before final step. Your can make "clean and build" project and see what is sequence of executed tasks, first, last etc.

I made an example of project pure Java Project in Netbeans, and when i run clean and build from menu i can see in output:

```
ant -f C:\Projects\NetBeansProjects\\Sample -Dnb.internal.action.name=build jar
init:
Deleting: C:\Projects\NetBeansProjects\Sample\build   \built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: C:\Projects\NetBeansProjects\Sample\build\built-jar.properties
compile:
Copying 1 file to C:\Projects\NetBeansProjects\Sample\build
Nothing to copy.
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "C:\Projects\NetBeansProjects\Sample\dist\Sample.jar"
zipme:
Building zip: C:\Projects\NetBeansProjects\Sample\examples\SampleProject.zip
jar:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Notice that there is **zipme** task which i took from your sample. Only changes i made is **jar** stage dependent from **zipme** stage

```
<target depends="init,compile,-pre-jar,-do-jar,-post-jar,zipme" description="Build JAR." name="jar"/>
```

In my case in simple java project there is no **build-init** stage. So i chose **jar** stage, since it is final in my case. Maybe u have another type of project (web, jee) and sequence of tasks and final stage might be different. It is actually not necessary define **zipme** task in final stage, just need to identify when exactly and in which case do u need **zipme** task executed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like u need a copy task in proper place in your task tree. 
It can be done after clean task and will copy templates from original location into dedicated directory in the module. Copy task support **overwrite** attribute in case if you have a lot of templates.

To generate zip just mark zip task as dependency to build task and zip archive will be generated every time you run **clean and build**.

Comment: i try `<target name="zipme"  description="Zip the application to the sample project"  depends="build-init,clean">` but it doesn't work